# Read an Aspose pdf from stream with IText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, aspose

I need to read a PDF created with Aspose, using ITextSharp.
Here is my code :

```
// instantiate Pdf object
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
// specify the Character encoding for for HTML file
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharSet = "UTF-8";
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharsetApplyingLevelOfForce = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.HtmlInfo.CharsetApplyingForceLevel.UseWhenImpossibleDetectFromContent;

// bind the source HTML
pdf.BindHTML(htmlString);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pdf.Save(stream);

Form form = new Form();
form.BindPdf(stream);

var inStream = new MemoryStream(Input.TemplateFile);

var pdfConcat = new PdfConcatenate(inStream);
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream);

pdfReader.SelectPages(new List<int>() { 0, 1 });
pdfConcat.AddPages(pdfReader);

pdfReader.Close();
pdfConcat.Close();
```

While debugging, I got the following error on line `var pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream);`

> PDF header signature not found

What I want to do :
 - Create one PDF page from an HTML string
 - Append it to an existing PDF

Any idea how to solve that issue ?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you try to grab the raw underlying bytes of your streams as soon as whatever is using it is done. For instance, `pdf.Save(stream);` saves to an empty `Stream`. Great! Call `ToArray()` on that to get the bytes so you can know, without a doubt, that you once again _own_ those bytes and no one else can doing anything with them. There's no pointers, "openess" or "closeness". If your next object requires a `Stream` you can easily re-wrap the bytes in a new `MemoryStream` such as for `form.BindPdf(stream);`. This will really help you with debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do a

```
form.BindPdf(stream);
```

before you give the stream to iTextSharp

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream);
```

The former operation already reads the stream leaving nothing to read for the `PdfReader`.

Probably a

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

right before the `PdfReader` initialization can properly rewind the stream.

---

If that does not work (e.g. if `form.BindPdf` does not merely read the stream but also manipulates it), retrieve a `byte[]` copy of the stream

```
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

*before* the `BindPdf` call and initialize the `PdfReader` with that:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);
```

Comment: This solve my issue. but I've got now an other one. My new page is not appended to my PDF. But it's another issue, I will dig a bit and post an other question if needed. Thanks :)

Comment: From above statement, do you mean HTML is not properly converted to PDF and hence its not appended to existing PDF ? If so is the case, can you please share your source/input HTML, so that we can test the conversion and share our findings.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.